# How can i use map function to store data in array in given dataset?

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, map-function

**Here is the main Data**
[Here is the main Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKzZG.png)

**Here is data of requests**
[Data Of request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7jI7.png)

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Without that it is unlikely we can help you better than the documentation or one of the many tutorials out there.

Comment: i tried but its not work

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"